# Change order of external and internal JS files

Tags: magento2, javascript

I'm trying to work with a geo ip API, and have included the JS for it in my `default_head_blocks` file, however it is being called after my own `geoip-api.js` file and therefore it's not picking up the Geo location until after my script has run.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="js/modernizr.js" />
        <script src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js" src_type="url"/>
        <link src="js/geoip-api.js" />

    </head>
</page>
```

How can I get the external script to be called before my theme file?

**EDIT:**

I've removed the link from the above code and instead used:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'maxmind': '//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2'
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal', 'maxmind'], function($, modal){
    #my code goes here;
});
```

However it's still running the maxmind JS after my code has run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the requirejs that is included with magento 2.

```
/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
```

Put a copy of this file in the root of your theme and then add in the files you need.

Guide to requirejs:
http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

Comment: Require Js is already in place, but I've had a look at this but it doesn't seem to be able to understand the external file and looks for an internal one. Can you find an example of using this with an externally hosted file? The guide doesn't have one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759151/how-do-i-load-third-party-javascript-from-a-cdn-when-using-requirejs

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to be working when I add that to my `requirejs-config.js` file. It keeps looking to a local file in my en_GB folder.

Comment: Can you share your new code? Have you removed the old references to the files?

Comment: I adeded the code for `requirejs.config` to the top of my js file and removed it from the default head blocks xml, which required it but still in the wrong order...